# Trouble deploying to Heroku ( "Application Error" )

Tags: heroku, deployment

The project is attached through my github and it builds successfully, when I click "Open App" I get this an "Application Error"...

My "log" on Heroku looks like:

```
Node.js app detected
Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 6.x...
   Downloading and installing node 6.11.2...
   Using default npm version: 3.10.10
Restoring cache
   Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
Building dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json)
Caching build
   Clearing previous node cache
   Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (nothing to cache)
Build succeeded!
Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> (none)
   Default types for buildpack -> web
Compressing...
   Done: 42.5M
Launching...
   Released v10
   https://ken-neiheisel-studio.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

And my package.json

[image: package.json]

Not sure exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently had same problem using Heroku for the 1st time, where everything looked right, the Build completed fine, yet I couldn't seem to not get the "Procfile declares types     -> (none)" error in the log.  I tried everything then realized I must have previously bad version of Procfile in that project that was invisible to me. I was looking at my visible Folders in Windows, where the Procfile was perfect.

To fix I deleted my Procfile from the projecct folder.  Did a fresh git add . and a fresh git commit -m "xxx" to load all the files to git/heroku...leaving Procfile out intentionally. That served to clear out the bad version of Procfile that was stored or cached in git or heroku.  Then I added a new Procfile to the folder.  Another git add . and commit -m, and finally all the weird errors surrounding the Procfile cleared and the App loaded to heroku/web.